# Creating JSON without quotes

Tags: jackson

A library is using Map to use some extra information. This map eventually is being converted a JSON object and I need to set request information to display for debugging purposes as this:

`map.put("request", requestString);`

I am considering to use Jackson specifically to create a JSON without quotes and want to set as `requestString`.

I am building necessary information regarding `Request` and building a Map including request headers, parameters, method etc.

Jackson is creating perfectly valid JSON with quotes but when I set this generated value inside map, It is displayed ugly because of having escaped quotes.

So Jackson is creating this:

```
{
   method : "POST",
   path : "/register"
}
```

When I set this in map, it turns to this:

```
{
   method : \"POST\",
   path : \"/register\"
}
```

Consider this as a huge map including all parameters and other information about request.

What I would like to want this:

```
{
   method : POST,
   path : /register
}
```

I know that this is not a valid JSON but I am using this as a String to a Map which is accepting String values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```java
public class UnQuotesSerializer extends NonTypedScalarSerializerBase<String>
{
   public UnQuotesSerializer() { super(String.class); }

   /**
    * For Strings, both null and Empty String qualify for emptiness.
    */
   @Override
   public boolean isEmpty(String value) {
      return (value == null) || (value.length() == 0);
   }

   @Override
   public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
      jgen.writeRawValue(value);
   }

   @Override
   public JsonNode getSchema(SerializerProvider provider, Type typeHint) {
      return createSchemaNode("string", true);
   }

   @Override
   public void acceptJsonFormatVisitor(JsonFormatVisitorWrapper visitor, JavaType typeHint) throws JsonMappingException {
      if (visitor != null) visitor.expectStringFormat(typeHint);
   }
}
```

and

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("UnQuote");
module.addSerializer(new UnQuotesSerializer());

objectMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

This is generating without quotes strings.

Answer (score 0):

The following test passes (`Jackson 2.5.0`)

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("method", "POST");
    map.put("request", "/register");
    String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    Map map2 = mapper.readValue(s, Map.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(map, map2);
}
```

so your pseudo JSON without quotes does not seem the way to go